# set closedDate to past for cases in unit tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, case

I have a requirement that uses filters based on closedDate for cases. 
When unit testing this logic I will need to create cases with a closeDate in the past but since it is not a writeable field I haven't got very far.
I have some options like creating a custom date field to capture the closeddate and use this in the unit tests or using test.loaddata which lets you write on audit fields(I haven't tried it with ClosedDate yet).
Has anyone come up with an efficient way of doing this? maybe looking at something like the **test.setCreatedDate** function but can't find anything similar for closeddate

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to get data from static resource. This will allow you to set back data. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm  for more details.

Comment: I added the "Case" tag, because I was thinking you were talking about the `CloseDate` field on `Opportunity` (which is writable) instead of the `ClosedDate` field on `Case` (which is, indeed, read-only)

Comment: the json deserialize solution is the right answer for this; for a nice wrapper that does all this in a readable way - see [GitHub sfab](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) - we use this all the time in our org to mock formula fields, custom metadata, etc.